# why is my register form not submitting?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

The problem with my form is that when i fill in everything correctly and the submit button doesn't do anything. My jQuery validation code are 100% working and i think the problem is at my php code. i JUST wonder if anyone can tell me the problem then i can fix it. **If you want to see my jquery validation script its at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2jwja5uy/)**

:/

html core

```
<div id="registerForm">
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="core/register.php" method="POST" class="registerForm form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username">Username:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<span></span>
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter a username">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<span></span>
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email - IMPORTANT">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="password">Password:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<span></span>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a password">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="confirmpassword">Confirm:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<span></span>
<input id="confirmpassword" type="password" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="code">Code:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<span></span>
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Register Code">
</div>
</div>
<div class="buttonspecial">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit" value="Register!">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

And my php code:

```
//FUNCTION
function register($register_data, $mysqli) {
$username       = $register_data['username'];
$password       = crypt($register_data['password'], PASSWORDSTRING);
$email          = $register_data['email'];
$email_code     = $register_data['email_code'];

if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, email_code, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())")){
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $password, $email, $email_code);

    if ($insert_stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
}

//WHERE FORM WILL BE SUBMITTED TO

 <?php
include_once("../core/init.php");

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])){
    $register_data = array(
    'username'          => $_POST['username'],
    'password'          => $_POST['password'],
    'email'             => $_POST['email'], 
    'email_code'        => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime() + $_POST['email']),
    );
    if (register($register_data, $mysqli) == true){
        header('Location: ../register_success.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
    }
}
?>
```

jquery Validation code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.registerForm').validate({
        // errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
        //     return true;
        // },
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                rangelength: [5, 20],
                remote: {
                    url: 'core/check/check.php',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        username: function () {
                            return $("#username").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                rangelength: [5, 50]
            },
            confirmpassword: {
                required: true,
                rangelength: [5, 50],
                equalTo: password
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: 'core/check/check.php',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function () {
                            return $("#email").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            code: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: 'core/check/check.php',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        code: function () {
                            return $("#code").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Enter a username.",
                rangelength: "Username must be 5 to 20 character",
                remote: "Username have been taken"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Enter a password.",
                rangelength: "Password must be 5 to 50 character",
                remote: "Email have been taken"
            },
            confirmpassword: {
                required: "Confirm your password.",
                rangelength: "Password must be 5 to 50 character",
                equalTo: "Your password does not match"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Enter your email(NOT SPAM EMAIL).",
                remote: "This Email have been taken"
            },
            code: {
                required: "Enter your Register Code",
                remote: "Invalid code or used code"
            },
            recaptcha_response_field: {
                required: "Do the reCaptcha",
                remote: 'Bad reCaptcha'
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error').find('.col-sm-10 span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success').find('.col-sm-10 span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback');
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

check.php

```
 <?php
include_once("../core/connect/db_connect.php");

// EMAIL
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
     $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
     $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

     $pre_stmt = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($pre_stmt);

     if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
            // CHECK IF EMAIL EXIST
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){
                echo "true";
                $stmt->close();
            } else {
                echo "false";
                $stmt->close();
            }

     }
}

// CODE
if (isset($_POST['code'])){
     $ccode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'code', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $code = md5(trim(strtolower($ccode)));

     $pre_stmt = "SELECT code FROM code WHERE code = ? AND used = 0";
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($pre_stmt);

     if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $code);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
            // CHECK IF CODE EXIST
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                echo 'true'; //OKAY
                $stmt->close();
            } else {
                echo 'false'; //NOTOK
                $stmt->close();
            }

     }
}

// USERNAME
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
     $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

     $pre_stmt = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($pre_stmt);

     if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
            // CHECK IF CODE EXIST
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){
                echo 'true';
                $stmt->close();
            } else {
                echo 'false';
                $stmt->close();
            }
     }
}


?>
```

Comment: Most likely because of this `md5($_POST['username'] + microtime() + $_POST['email'])` that's not the right type of concatenate. `+` is a JS/C+ method. Checking for errors would have thrown an error in that regard.

Comment: Plus, I don't see where you're using a POST variable for `name="code"`

Comment: oh, that just for my jquery validation remote method. If the code is right, it turn green else turn red. Dont worry about the code. :)

Comment: You're inside PHP with that, not JS. Two different animals altogether. But, if you say so.

Comment: Change `=> md5($_POST['username'] + microtime() + $_POST['email']),` to `=> md5($_POST['username'] . microtime() . $_POST['email']),` just try it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- is likely correct about that so I'd pay attention to him.  However, the form is not submitting because your jQuery Validate `submitHandler` is broken.  You are trying to use a function argument that you've failed to pass into the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem...

```
submitHandler: function () {
    form.submit();
}
```

1. You forgot to pass the `form` argument into the function.  The `submitHandler` takes over and prevents the native form submit; and it can't do anything with `form.submit()` since the `form` does not exist here.  It should look more like this...

   ```
   submitHandler: function (form) { // <- need to pass the 'form' argument here
       $(form).submit();
   }
   ```
2. HOWEVER, since a `.submit()` of the native `form` action is just what the plugin would already do by default, you do not need the `submitHandler` at all.  The whole thing is superfluous.  Remove it.  **Remove the entire `submitHandler` option.**

*(The `submitHandler` is only needed when you want to do something else, like submit the entire form via `ajax()`.)*

---

**NOTES**:

Your `remote` method is using the `data` option...

```
rules: {
    username: {
        // other rules,
        remote: {
            url: 'core/check/check.php',
            type: "post",
            data: {
                username: function () {
                    return $("#username").val();
                }
            }
        }
    }, ....
```

The `data` option is not needed for the `username` field, because the value of ***this*** field is *already* sent by default with `remote`.

```
rules: {
    username: {
        // other rules,
        remote: {
            url: 'core/check/check.php',
            type: "post"
        }
    }, ....
```

*(The `data` option would only be needed if you wanted to send some **other additional** data along with this `remote` request.)*

---

You have even more superfluousness here...

```
password: {
    required: true,
    rangelength: [5, 50]
},
confirmpassword: {
    required: true,
    rangelength: [5, 50],
    equalTo: password
},
```

When using the `equalTo` rule, it mandates that the `confirmpassword` field exactly match the `password` field.  This means that you could not leave `confirmpassword` blank or put in the wrong number of characters because it already ***must*** match the `password` field.

This will work practically the same...

```
password: {
    required: true,
    rangelength: [5, 50]
},
confirmpassword: {
    required: true,  // <- I left this one for an initial empty form
    equalTo: password
},
```

---

BTW:  You can simply use the placeholders within your error messages.  The correct values will get inserted dynamically.

```
rangelength: "Username must be {0} to {1} characters",
```

**Your DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2jwja5uy/1/**

Same DEMO with `remote` methods removed so you can see it fire the submit:  http://jsfiddle.net/2jwja5uy/2/